# How to generate a PDF with custom font with xhtml2pdf on App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, font-face, temporary-files, xhtml2pdf

xhtml2pdf works fine to generate a simple PDF on App Engine.

But now I need to add a custom font in the generated PDF, and I don't seem to find an easy solution to do this.

I added this CSS to the HTML to convert to PDF:

```
    @font-face {
       font-family: OpenSans;
       src: url("http://mydomain/fonts/Open-Sans-regular.ttf");
    }
    body {
        font-family: OpenSans;
    }
```

Which yields this error:

```
  File "[..]/xhtml2pdf/util.py", line 613, in getNamedFile
self.tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist/tempfile.py", line 61, in PlaceHolder
  raise NotImplementedError("Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use")
  NotImplementedError: Only tempfile.TemporaryFile is available for use
```

`tempfile` is not supported by GAE, so I have tried to replace `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` by creating a temporary file in GCS like this:

```
self.tmp_file = gcs.open('/gcs_bucket_temp/temp_file', 
                         'w',
                         retry_params=gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1))
```

but that creates breaking changes that are difficult to fix: xhtml2pdf makes a lot of read accesses to the tempfile in `ttfonts.py` (e.g. ttfonts.py:321 `unpack('>L',self._ttf_data[self._pos - 4:self._pos])[0]`), which seems difficult to migrate over to work with a GCS file.

Has anyone been able to generate PDFs using xhtml2pdf on App Engine, with custom fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the changes to xhtml2pdf library I had to make to allow custom @font-face support on App Engine. Basically using GCS to store the tempfile instead of the file system.

In `ttfonts.py:239`, replace:

```
self.filename, f = TTFOpenFile(f)
self._ttf_data = f.read()
```

by:

```
self.filename = f
gcs_file = gcs.open(f) #, 'w', retry_params=gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1))
self._ttf_data = gcs_file.read()
gcs_file.close()
```

In `util.py:608`, replace:

```
self.tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
if self.file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(self.file, self.tmp_file)
else:
    self.tmp_file.write(self.getData())
    self.tmp_file.flush()
return self.tmp_file
```

by:

```
filename = '/%s/temp_file'%gcs_bucket
self.tmp_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', retry_params=gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1))
if self.file:
    self.tmp_file.write(self.file._fetch_response.content)
else:
    self.tmp_file.write(self.getData())
self.tmp_file.close()
return filename
```

This seems to do the trick. Custom fonts appear well in the generated PDFs now.